# How to select all h tags starting from a certain number (XPath)?

Tags: html, xml, xpath, xml-namespaces

I want to select all `h` tags starting, for example, from the tag `h3`, i.e. `h3`, `h4`, `h5`... I know how to select only `h3`:

```
//h:h3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### XPath 1.0

Keep it simple and just enumerate them:

```
//*[self::h:h3 or self::h:h4 or self::h:h5 or self::h:h6]
```

### XPath 2.0

You can use regex in various ways.  For example...

For all tags of the form `h`*number*:

```
//*[matches(local-name(),'^h\d+$')]
```

For a limited range of a single digit:

```
//*[matches(local-name(),'^h[3-6]$')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
//*[matches(name(), '^h\d')]
```

if there are namespaces in element name then use:

```
//*[matches(local-name(), '^h\d')]
```

Comment: I don't see any numbers. Will it work for the tags: h3, h4, h5...? I don't need h1 and h2 tags.

Comment: Then use `//*[matches(local-name(), '^h[3-6]')]` for h3 to h6 give the range.